# Docker in unprivileged LXC container freezes host system

Tags: virtualization, docker, lxc

I am running docker in an unprivileged LXC container (alpine) on a proxmox host system. The container has nesting enabled. What i discover is that on high memory consumption in the container, the whole host system becomes unresponsive. Only help is a hard reset.

I have read that there seems to be a kernel bug: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14487

Bug the bug is reported in 2015, the current kernel version should have this issue fixed (i guess).

Comment: Where do you see that a kernel bug was fixed? I can't even see that it was ever reported!

Comment: I have not seen that it was fixed. Other question is: Is this a kernel bug?

Comment: Who knows? The maintainers who commented on that issue seemed to think it was.